# first order quadratic ode

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the ODE $$x'(t)=a^2-b^2x(t)^2$$ with $x(0) = 0$ and $a,b>0$. From WolframAlpha I know that a solution is $x(t) = \frac{a\tan(ab(c+t))}{b}$ ignoring $x(0) = 0$ for now. I have tried to "reverse engineer" this solution. For instance, since I don't own WolframAlpha Pro, but I can see the first two steps of the solution, WolframAlpha rewrites the equation to $$\int \frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{a^2-b^2x^2}dt = \int 1 dt.$$ I know that physicists often use a trick and cut "$dt$'s" with one another like $\frac{dx}{dt} \cdot dt = dx$. But that does not seem to help me.

Another idea that didn't bring me far was to rewrite my ode to $$x'=(a-bx)(a+bx),$$ where I could use integration by parts. Here the problem is I am integrating with respect to t and I don't know anything about $x(t)$.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x'(t) = \cfrac{dx}{dt}$$
$$\cfrac{dx}{dt} = a^2 - b^2 x(t)^2 \ |  \cdot \cfrac{dt}{a^2 - b^2 x(t)^2 }$$
$$\cfrac{dx}{a^2 - b^2 x(t)^2} = dt$$
$$\int_{x(t_0)}^{x} \cfrac{dx}{a^2 - b^2 x(t)^2} = \int_{t_0}^t dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{x} \cfrac{dx}{a^2 - b^2 x(t)^2} = \int_{0}^t dt$$
$$\cfrac{1}{b^2}\int_{0}^{x} \cfrac{dx}{\cfrac{a^2}{b^2} - x(t)^2} = \int_{0}^t dt$$
$$\cfrac{1}{ab} \tanh \left(\cfrac{bx}{a} \right) = t$$
$$\tanh(bx/a) = abt$$
$$x = \cfrac{a \tanh^{-1}(abt)}{b}$$

Comment: its $a^2-b^2x^2$, you just solved for $a^2+b^2x^2$

Comment: anyways, since arctan is point symmetric I can confirm WolframAlpha's solution. Both minus sign cancel therefore. So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For this right side you can also start with the substitution
$$
u(t)=\frac{bx(t)-a}{bx(t)+a}
$$
which has derivative
$$
u'(t)=\frac{2ab\,x'(t)}{(bx(t)+a)^2}
=-2ab\frac{bx(t)-a}{bx(t)+a}=-2ab\,u(t)
$$
which is now easy to solve.

---

It is somewhat too powerful to treat this as Riccati equation, but if you do and set $x=\frac{u}{v}$, then
$$
u'v-v'u=a^2v^2-b^2u^2\\
\iff (u'-a^2v)v=(v'-b^2u)u
$$
leading to the linear system
$$
u'=a^2v\\
v'=b^2u
$$
or $u''=a^2b^2u$, which again has an easy solution in exponentials.